# Use a variable on Backbone.history.navigate in backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

how to use a variable on Backbone view ?

If i work like this (below)... This does not work.

```
App.Views.Incentive = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: $('#projet-page'),
        name: "Incentive",
        initialize: function () {
            "use strict";
            $('section[data-projet-page="' + this.name + '"] a.OpenGalerie').on('click', this.enterGalerieClick);
        },
        enterProjectClick: function () {
            Backbone.history.navigate('!/case-projet/' + this.name + '/Galerie'),
            $('section[data-projet-page="' + this.name + '"]').css('display', 'block'),
        },

    });
```

i have :

**domain:9000/#!/case-projet//Galerie** instead of **domain:9000/#!/case-projet/Incentive/Galerie**

Comment: What doesn't work. The way you're accessing the name variable is correct.

Comment: In return, i have this.name = "" (empty). Not "Incentive"

Comment: You've actually removed the piece of code which I think is problematic. I'm not convinced you should be handling clicks on elements other than the element associated with the view, or children of it. However, your click handler is not being called in the scope of the view, rather this will be the element it is bound to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the immediate problem by using underscore's `bind` method (see [documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#bind)) to ensure that `this` in the click handler refers to the Backbone view and not the element you've bound the handler to:

```
App.Views.Incentive = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: $('#projet-page'),
        name: "Incentive",
        initialize: function () {
            "use strict";
            $('section[data-projet-page="' + this.name + '"] a.OpenGalerie').on('click', _.bind(this.enterGalerieClick, this));
        },
        enterProjectClick: function () {
            Backbone.history.navigate('!/case-projet/' + this.name + '/Galerie'),
            $('section[data-projet-page="' + this.name + '"]').css('display', 'block'),
        },

    });
```